# Yes/no : Is the given sequence is cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Yes/no : Is  the given sequence  is cauchy ?

> let  $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \notin [n-1,n+1] \\ x-n+1 & \text{if } x\in [n-1,n]\\ n+1-x & \text{if } x\in [n,n+1]
> \end{cases}$$ in the space $\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\mid  f\text{ is continuous and } \int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}|f(t)|\,dt<\infty\right\}$ equipped with $d_1$ metric

Note : $d_1$-metric on a space  of function defined over  a domain $ X$ subset $\mathbb{R}$ whenever it is  well  defined  as follows
 $d_1(f,g)  = \int_{X} |f(x)  - g(x) | dx$

MY attempt :$ d(f_n ,f) =  \int_{0} ^{n-1} 0 dx + \int_{n-1}^{n+1} ( x-n+1 - x-n +1) dx=\int_{n-1}^{n+1} 2dx=2(n+1-n+1)=4 \neq 0$

so $d(f_n,f) \neq 0$ that mean not cauchy

Is its true ?

Comment: You have to compute $d(f_n, f_m)$ to decide Cauchy-ness. There is no $f$ involved!

Comment: oh  sorry sir @HennoBrandsma sir

Comment: $f_n$ is discontinuous at $x=n$.

Comment: @Izralbu  it is continious at $x= n$ see again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sequence to be Cauchy we need $\lim_{\ m\to\infty}d_m=0$ where $$d_m=\sup_{n>m}\ d_1(f_m,f_n)\to 0\text{ as }m\to\infty$$

Notice that $f_n(x)=0$ except on $(n-1,n+1)$, but $>n$ on half that interval.

So if $m+2<n$, then $d_1(f_m,f_m)>m$, so the sequence is not Cauchy.

In fact it fails to be Cauchy so spectacularly that I suspect the question was meant to be $f_n(x)=x-n-1$, not $x+n-1$, for $x\in[n,n+1]$. Because even that case fails to be Cauchy (by a similar argument - for large enough $n$, $f_n$ fails to cancel out the contribution of $f_m$ to the integral, because it is zero wherever $f_m(x)\ne0$).

Comment: it  is  $n+ 1- x $  i have  edits  now  seee again @Almagest